# Simplify does not work when trying to simplify an expression to a letter

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to simplify the following expression

$$ \frac{\phi^2 + \varepsilon^2}{\phi\varepsilon} $$ to a letter, let's say $a$.

Thus I tried something on the line of

```
assump = {d ∈ PositiveReals, (ϵ^2 + ϕ^2)/(ϵ ϕ) == a};

Simplify[(ϵ^2 + ϕ^2)/(ϵ ϕ), Assumptions -> assump]
```

but nothing changes... Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and maybe explain to me how I could have this expression simplified to a letter? I was expecting something like this:

```
Simplify[(ϵ^2 + ϕ^2)/(ϵ ϕ), Assumptions -> someAssumptions]
(* Output: a *)
```

Comment: Tip: It's nice to provide code in a form that can be copied, pasted, and executed directly. Makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Try: ReplaceAll